# Clarity on Textbook Example on showing a sequence is decreasing (Stewart MultiVariable Calculus)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was studying a topic and got stuck on one of the given textbook examples that demonstrate how to show that a sequence is decreasing. The question and argument is as followed:

Show that the sequence $a_n = \frac{(n)}{(n^2+1)}$ is decreasing.
The question gives an argument to show $a_n > a_{n+1}$

$\frac{(n)}{(n^2+1)}$ > $ \frac{(n+1)}{(n+1)^2 +1}$

(Cross multiplying we get)

$n[(n+1)^2 + ] > (n+1)(n^2+1)$   ~~~line A

$n^3 + 2n^2+2n> n^3 +n^2+n+1$   ~~~ Line B

$n^2 + n > 1$     ~~~ Line c

And here lies my confusion. Maybe it might just be that I am still inexperienced when working with inequalities, and my eyes may still be untrained. But from my novice perspective, I don't see how it was shown that $a_n > a_n+1$ , on line a and b we cross multiplied and then expanded each side. But I'am confused with line c, I know we subtract the rhs from both sides, but it seems we don't subtract the 1 from the rhs and we just left it on the rhs. I have a hard time accepting this, because how can we say we have shown the lhs is greater than the rhs, if we "left-out" part of the quantity of $a_(n+1)$ during our comparison(i.e the  1)?  To me it feels as if the question started off with the intent to show A > B, and then concluded by showing A > (B - 1 ).

I know one of the ways of showing that a number is bigger than another, is by subtracting the two quantities, and if the difference is positive, then the first quantity is larger. Would it have been more appropriate to subtract the entire RHS? As in $ n^2+n-1> 0$ . As we are working with a sequence we know that n is an integer greater than or equal to 1. If I am missing why the given argument is valid, can someone please explain to me what I am missing? Thank you

Comment: Stewart's book is notoriously bad. Yes, that sequence of inequalities is what you do to discover the proof. The deduction, the implications, go in the reverse order. You can start from $n^2+n>1$, which you know, or can prove is true and then add on both sides the same amounts to get to Line B.

Comment: From Line B to Line A, you divide by the denominators, but one must at least mention that they are positive.

Comment: And the approach in your last paragraph, yes, is another approach that is correct.

Comment: Ohhh its in reverse, thank you very much for the clarity

Comment: The function $f(x) = {x \over 1+x^2}$ has $f'(x) = {1-x^2 \over (1+x^2)^2}$ and $f'(x) \le 0$ for $x \ge 1$, and $f'(x) < 0$ for $x>1$. Hence $f(n)$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have presented is correct proof that the given sequence is decreasing.

I think your confusion arises from your assumption that between lines B and C, you subtract the entire right-hand side, and so you then cannot account for the remaining 1 on the right-hand side of line C.

However, that's not quite the algebraic manipulation performed. Let's go through the steps:

$ a_n = \frac{n^2}{n+1} $ is strictly decreasing if $a_n > a_{n+1}$ as you correctly mentioned. Now we want to proceed through a series of equivalent statements to reach something we know is true. So:

$$ a_n > a_{n+1} \Longleftrightarrow \frac{n}{n^2+1} > \frac{n+1}{(n+1)^2+1} \Longleftrightarrow n[(n+1)^2+1] > (n^2+1)(n+1)$$ since both $n^2+1 $ and $(n^2+1)+1$ are positive. Then by expanding, we get:

$$ n(n^2+2n+1+1) > n^3 + n^2+n+1 \Longleftrightarrow n^3+2n^2+2n > n^3+n^2+n+1$$

Crucially, here we don't just subtract the rhs from both sides like you suggested, instead we only subtract  $n^3, n^2$
and $n$ from both sides and we get:

$$ n^3 + 2n^2 + 2n - n^3 - n^2 - n > n^3 + n^2 + n + 1 - n^3 - n^2 - n \Longleftrightarrow n^2 + n > 1 $$

which we know is true for any $n \ge 1$

We started from the statement we wanted to show, namely that the sequence is decreasing and arrived at something we know is true, and so we are done.

Comment: I am still new to mathematical proof,  but i have some background from a previous logic course. I know that proofs are done a little bit differently in math compared to logic, but imagine they still share some general conventions.  I know for instance that there is a consensus that you can't derive a true statement from a false premise. So if there was a takeaway point that I can get from my question, is it common in mathematical proofs to verify the premise by simply deriving some true statement? If so, then i will know to take this into account whenever I read future proofs

Comment: (Mathematical) logic is an area of mathematics. The principles of proof writing from logic are the same ones used in calculus, analysis, etc. What changes, is the level of rigor expected. Writing the above, in formal proof-writing style, you would aim to show $\forall n \in N^+. a_n < a_{n+1}$, which is a first-order formula, which we show is equivalent to $\top$. Showing validity through equivalences is indeed a very common proof technique known as direct proof. Lastly, a false premise implies anything, i.e. $\bot \rightarrow \top$ is a true statement. It's the opposite that's false.